# Count number of wins grouped by football team

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have table, *matches*, where I store football matches between two teams, *local* and *visitor*. I then also store if the local team won, *localwin*, as a tinyint(1) - 1 if they won and 0 if they lost. My table looks like this

```
local           visitor       localwin
Manchester      Barcelona         1
Manchester      Real Madrid       0
Real Madrid     Bayern            0
Bayern          Barcelona         1
```

How would I count the number of times the different teams won?

I know I probably need a COUNT and a GROUP BY, but I am not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression to produce the winner, and then group by it and count the occurrences:

```
SELECT   CASE localwin WHEN 1 THEN local ELSE visitor END, COUNT(*)
FROM     matches
GROUP BY CASE localwin WHEN 1 THEN local ELSE visitor END
```

**Note:**
This query assumes that if the local team didn't win, the visitor did, i.e., there are no draws. If drawing is an option, the `case` expression may need some tweaking.

Comment: In my matches there are no draws :P. This solved the issue, thank you for the quick and correct answer. I will accept it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
select t.team, count(m.localwin) wins
from (
  select local team from matches
  union
  select visitor team from matches
) t left join matches m
on t.team = (case m.localwin when 1 then m.local else m.visitor end) 
group by t.team
```

will also include teams that have `0` wins.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tmG6LTELFbawG3Ydbhi4Fk/0)